# Notepad++: Finding two consecutive real numbers with arbitrary decimal part

Tags: regex

Consider the following line:

```
ATOM  41108  ZN1 ION     1       23.520  23.143 -1.003  1.00  0.00      O1
```

Suppose I want to find this line where there is 23.* 23.* after each other in the same line.

I tried `23\d*\s*23` but it doesn't find this test line.

Comment: You missed decimal points `23(?:\.\d+)?\s*23(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: @revo Thank you, now it works!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for digits while there is a decimal point right before `23`:

```
23\.\d+\s*23\.\d+
```

If fractional parts are optional you could do this:

```
23(?:\.\d+)?\s*23(?:\.\d+)?
```